# ScreenRecording OutOfRange

Tags: outofrangeexception, screen-recording

I drew a rectangle to capture my screen. It captures with the properties I want,resolution is perfect... However my screen recorder doesn't record my entire screen. When I try to increase the values (the width and the height of the rectangle) I take an `OutOfRangeExpection` Error. The rectangle is smaller than the screen! How can I increase the size of my rectangle without taking an `OutOfRangeExpection`. here where I draw my rectangle :

```
   Job = new ScreenCaptureJob();
        System.Drawing.Size Ekran = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorMaximizedWindowSize;
        Rectangle CaptureRect = new Rectangle(0,0, Ekran.Width,Ekran.Height);
Job.CaptureRectangle = CaptureRect;
```